# Equivalence between coactions and actions plus a linearization line bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-actions, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $G$ be an algebraic group over a field $k$, and $\mathbb{P}(V)$ is a projective space. Then Mumford said in his book *Geometric Invariant Theory* that there's a equivalence between the set of all dual actions of $G$ on $H^0(\mathbb{P}(V), \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(V)} (1))$ and the set of all actions of $G$ on $\mathbb{P}(V)$ plus a $G$-linearization of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(V)}(1)$.

This appears in the proof of Proposition 1.7 at the page 35 .

I have no idea on how to prove this statement...

[image]

Comment: What is a coaction? The term does not appear in Mumford's book.

Comment: @abx Sorry, I mean the dual action.

Comment: Are you aware that $H^0(\mathbb{P}(V),\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(1))=V^*$? That helps...

Comment: @abx  It seems that $H^0(\mathbb{P}(V), \mathcal{O}(1))=V$ in this book... I add the picture of the proof of Proposition 1.7 in question.

Comment: For any line bundle $L$ on a variety $X$, a $G$-linearization induces a linear action of $G$ on $H^0(X,L)$. Conversely, a linear action of $G$ on $V$ induces an action on $\mathbb{P}(V)$ with a $G$-linearization of $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(1)$.

Comment: @abx Can you give any more details about the "Conversely" part? Thanks!

Comment: Use the surjective homomorphism $V\otimes _{\mathbb{C}}\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}}\rightarrow \mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(1)$. The  natural $\operatorname{GL}(V) $-linearization of   $V\otimes _{\mathbb{C}}\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}}$ induces one on $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(1)$.

Comment: @abx Now I got it. Thank you!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to have been answered to the poster's satisfaction in a comment.